# Хранение файлов программы

Tags: java

Привет. Пишу desktop-приложение. В папке

```
..../username/AppFolder/
```

создается файл с нужными данными для работы программы, но если пользователь полезет туда и изменит его, то программа работает уже некорректно. Как лучше хранить этот файл? Read-only не вариант, так как само приложение периодически туда дописывает информацию. Хотел хранить в самом JAR, но читал, что это плохой вариант.

Comment: полез**е**т, пер**и**одически

Comment: @thejadefalcon допустим, вы покупаете телефон. На него есть гарантия, которая обещает вам, что при надлежащей эксплуатации ваш девайс прослужит вам верой и правдой N лет/месяцев. Однако если вы, наприме, вскроете этот телефон и начнете что-то там ковырять в его внутренностях, то гарантия, разумеетсяЮ, аннулируется, что вполне логично. То же самое применимо и к вашей программе. Конечно, никаких гарантийных талонов с софтом обычно не поставляют, но принцип тот же.

Comment: @thejadefalcon, а почему Вас не волнует, например, что пользователь может просто отформатировать диск?